# Loading contents when scrolling task bar

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a webpage, http://localhost/index.php , which serves contents without paging, each contents are displayed as follows, likewise there are unlimited contents

```
<li class="myitems">
  ---CONTENTS-1------
</li>


<li class="myitems">
  ---CONTENTS-2------
</li>
```

What I need to acquire through jQuery ajax is , I need to load each 5 contents when user scrolls at the bottom of page. Explaining 5 contents will display when first page loads, then load next 5 contents when user scrolls at the end of page likewise increment the contents when user reaches the end of page...

Can any one explain how can I do this ?

Comment: How are your items stored?
Have you tried anything?

Comment: I had tried by setting paging and loading contents based on page result, but it fails as some times certain pages make empty page results, can advice anything based on above theory ?

Comment: Need to show relevant code that isn't working. See [mcve]